# installing PyQt4 cannot find -lpython3.1mu

Tags: ubuntu, pyqt4, python-3.2

recently I upgraded my Ubuntu from 10.04 to 11.04. Now I'm having trouble installing PyQt4 for python 3.2. It worked fine for 3.1. When I do sudo make install after a while I get following error:

```
make[1]: Entering directory `/home/john/Python/PyQt-x11-gpl-4.8.5/designer
rm -f libpythonplugin.so
g++ -Wl,-O1 -shared -o libpythonplugin.so pluginloader.o moc_pluginloader.o   -L/usr/lib -L/usr/lib -lpython3.1mu -lQtScript -lQtXml -lQtGui -lQtCore -lQtDesigner -lpthread  
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lpython3.1mu
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
make[1]: *** [libpythonplugin.so] Error 1
make[1]: Leaving directory `/home/john/Python/PyQt-x11-gpl-4.8.5/designer'
make: *** [install] Error 2
```

It's really strange I googled for hours and didn't find any solution. Normally I wouldn't really mind it and just used python 3.1 but pyuic4 keeps complaining that it cannot import PyQt4 module because it's using python 3.2.

Answer (score 0):

You need to install the python3-dev packages from apt repos, just to be safe i would run the following commands `sudo apt-get update`, because you can never go wrong with a fresh package listing :). and then to install `sudo apt-get install python3.1-dev python3.2-dev python3-dev` you really only need python3.1-dev, but installing `python3.2-dev` and `python3-dev` can't *really* hurt either

Comment: I have python3.1-dev and python3.2-dev already installed and updated to newest version. That was one of first things I checked.

Comment: hmmmm, I've always had problems with PyQt4 Install, Don't you need SIP installed? I think it has something to with the linker. I remember having this same damn annoying problem with ERIC IDE. Just ran a quick ld test, try running ld -lpython3.2mu and post your bash log.

Comment: I know I need SIP I'm using 4.12.4. OK I run ld -lpython3.2mu and I got ld: warning: cannot find entry symbol _start; not setting start address

Comment: now if you run ld -lpython3.1mu it says something like cannot find right? Then try ld -lpython3.1 (Without mu) and see what it says. Lots of trial and error, sorry if this annoys you!  Also, search on google to find things like `pyqt4 ppa` so you can install everything in one go on your system.